# What is Difference Between Console.WriteLine($"welcome{name}") and Console.WriteLine("welcome {0}",name)

Tags: c#

I have taken
String name="Max";
when I going to print a name like this, what operation was done under this.

```
Console.WriteLine($"welcome{name}")
```

and

```
 Console.WriteLine("welcome {0}",name).
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it yourself? Apart from the missing space in the first example which I assume is a typo the output would be the same and they're both just string interpolation. Are you asking what literally happens "under the hood"?

Comment: The difference is there is a space in second string.

Answer (score 2):

Both are same. This is called `String Interpolation`. For more information read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Before C# version 6 (`Console.WriteLine` works as `String.Format`)

```
Console.WriteLine("welcome " + name) //with + operator

string newstring = string.Format("welcome {0}", name) //with string.format

Console.WriteLine("welcome {0}", name) //same as string.format
```

`$` is introduced with C# version 6 to simplify `String Interpolation`

```
Console.WriteLine($"welcome {name}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Though both doing the same things but has few differences.

```
 Console.WriteLine("welcome {0}",name)
```

> As first one you are passing your value as parameter which belongs to
>   `{0}` place holder.

On  the other hand,

```
Console.WriteLine($"welcome{name}")`
```

> Secondly, `$` is introduced with [C# version 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#string-interpolation) where value directly passed
>   on the container. `$ String interpolation`  working here as place
>   holder

Hope this would help.